# How is something like this made in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I thought drawing a hexagon then using something like the blend tool but the angles at the end seem difficult.

[image]

Comment: What have you tired? It's merely a series of paths.

Comment: I created a hexagon, blend tool to create three paths then began removing points. However, it the angles of the end always fails to match.

Comment: Expand the paths to shapes, then adjust angles on end caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a grid of lines. Have a bunch of equally spaced vertical lines and make +60 degrees and minus 60 degrees rotated copies. Group the lines for easy selection. Select the lines. Fill the areas with the shape builder. You can make it in pieces and continue from the earlier ones.

[image]

You can well draw a sketch before filling with the shape builder (which is destructive tool). Do not select the sketch when you select the grid for filling.

Finally ungroup all and move your new shapes to elsewhere or delete the grid. Use "Select the same" to get everything selected easily.

As you see the gap is in your example smaller than the width of the yellowish lines. You can insert a stroke to the generated shapes. I guess it was finally pasted to  Photoshop and Layer style Bevel&Emboss was added to get the metallic appearance. It can be outer bevel, so no stroke is needed to reduce the gaps.

[image]

This bevel is what happened to come out. The dialog has plenty of adjustments which affect radically. Find a good version for your purposes.

Illustrator's 3D effect Extrude & Bevel can also create  metallic looking edges. You must insert a stroke to get wider stripes, expand the stroke and unite it with the original stripe and make all corners round because sharp corners cause math errors in 3D bevels.

[image]

This was tricky. I do not recommend it.

**One option is still left for the edges**: The stroke can be filled with gradient or art brush. I skip them because good result needs modern Illustrator, not my museum grade version.